# Spark Structured Streaming StateStore Exception with RocksDBStateStoreProvider

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming, rocksdb

I'm developing a Spark structured streaming application with a **stream-stream join** logic, leveraging RocksDB as the backbone for storing the state. The setup includes Kafka as the source for my streams, and I'm using Java 17 and Spark 3.5.0 in **local** mode.
I'm encountering an issue in my Spark structured streaming application that involves stream-stream join. I want to use **RocksDB** as my Spark application state store. I have configured the state store provider using **spark.sql.streaming.stateStore.providerClass** to be **org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.RocksDBStateStoreProvider**. After running multiple batches, I'm facing the following exception. I cleaned the check point directory multiple time and rerun the app and the exception happened every time. there is a **many to one** relationship between the join id's in my source streams and I couldn't find any data corruption in my source streams. I'm using Kafka as a source for my streams, running Spark locally, and utilizing a Windows directory as the checkpoint directory.

I also tried spark version 3.4.0 but the exception still happened.
I appreciate any insights or guidance on resolving this issue. Thank you!

````
org.rocksdb.RocksDBException: Mismatch in unique ID on table file 27. Expected: {7568779327299478048,6781697239205038417} Actual: {7568779327299478056,2042577083335893353} in file C:\Windows\Temp\spark-fed38dd1-aae2-45ab-ad2f-8e0f02ea223b\StateStoreId(opId=0,partId=1,name=left-keyWithIndexToValue)-a692f8b0-e03c-4475-8925-0d589f67d628\workingDir-c71dca44-dcbc-4057-91d2-afce3d7cb7b4/MANIFEST-000005
    at org.rocksdb.RocksDB.open(Native Method) ~[rocksdbjni-8.3.2.jar!/:?]
    at org.rocksdb.RocksDB.open(RocksDB.java:249) ~[rocksdbjni-8.3.2.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.RocksDB.openDB(RocksDB.scala:584) ~[spark-sql_2.12-3.5.0.jar!/:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.RocksDB.load(RocksDB.scala:154) ~[spark-sql_2.12-3.5.0.jar!/:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.RocksDBStateStoreProvider.getStore(RocksDBStateStoreProvider.scala:194) ~[spark-sql_2.12-3.5.0.jar!/:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.StateStore$.get(StateStore.scala:507) ~[spark-sql_2.12-3.5.0.jar!/:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.SymmetricHashJoinStateManager$StateStoreHandler.getStateStore(SymmetricHashJoinStateManager.scala:417) ~[spark-sql_2.12-3.5.0.jar!/:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.SymmetricHashJoinStateManager$KeyWithIndexToValueStore.<init>(SymmetricHashJoinStateManager.scala:600) ~[spark-sql_2.12-3.5.0.jar!/:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.SymmetricHashJoinStateManager.<init>(SymmetricHashJoinStateManager.scala:386) ~[spark-sql_2.12-3.5.0.jar!/:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamingSymmetricHashJoinExec$OneSideHashJoiner.<init>(StreamingSymmetricHashJoinExec.scala:529) ~[spark-sql_2.12-3.5.0.jar!/:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamingSymmetricHashJoinExec.processPartitions(StreamingSymmetricHashJoinExec.scala:276) ~[spark-sql_2.12-3.5.0.jar!/:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamingSymmetricHashJoinExec.$anonfun$doExecute$1(StreamingSymmetricHashJoinExec.scala:241) ~[spark-sql_2.12-3.5.0.jar!/:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamingSymmetricHashJoinExec.$anonfun$doExecute$1$adapted(StreamingSymmetricHashJoinExec.scala:241) ~[spark-sql_2.12-3.5.0.jar!/:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamingSymmetricHashJoinHelper$StateStoreAwareZipPartitionsRDD.compute(StreamingSymmetricHashJoinHelper.scala:295) ~[spark-sql_2.12-3.5.0.jar!/:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:364) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.5.0.jar!/:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:328) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.5.0.jar!/:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.5.0.jar!/:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:364) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.5.0.jar!/:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:328) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.5.0.jar!/:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecutionRDD.compute(SQLExecutionRDD.scala:55) ~[spark-sql_2.12-3.5.0.jar!/:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:364) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.5.0.jar!/:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:328) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.5.0.jar!/:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.5.0.jar!/:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:364) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.5.0.jar!/:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:328) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.5.0.jar!/:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.5.0.jar!/:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:364) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.5.0.jar!/:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:328) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.5.0.jar!/:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecutionRDD.compute(SQLExecutionRDD.scala:55) ~[spark-sql_2.12-3.5.0.jar!/:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:364) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.5.0.jar!/:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:328) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.5.0.jar!/:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.5.0.jar!/:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:364) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.5.0.jar!/:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:328) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.5.0.jar!/:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:93) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.5.0.jar!/:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:161) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.5.0.jar!/:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:141) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.5.0.jar!/:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:620) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.5.0.jar!/:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64) ~[spark-common-utils_2.12-3.5.0.jar!/:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61) ~[spark-common-utils_2.12-3.5.0.jar!/:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:94) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.5.0.jar!/:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:623) [spark-core_2.12-3.5.0.jar!/:3.5.0]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [?:?]```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My use case is quite similar, I'm using Kafka as a source for my streams, and I'm doing lots of stateful operations.

I was running Spark in production since a year in version **3.3.2** and everything was working fine, until I tried last week to upgrade from 3.3.2 to **3.5.0**. The streams were working fine in our tests environments, but ended up crashing in production after a few hundreds of batches (probably because of the quantity of data) with the exact same error.

I tried a few things, but nothing worked. I ended up **downgrading** my Spark to version 3.3.2, and everything is working again.

If you really want to stick to 3.5.0, I think that setting `spark.shuffle.service.db.backend` to `LEVELDB`, and removing the `RocksDBStateStoreProvider` should fix your problem.

Comment: thanks. I am sure about my the data quality, since I have done a lot of test in the time of getting the exception. it seems to be a bug in spark version > 3.3.2. I have tested two version of spark 3.4.0 and 3.5.0, and get the exception in both of them.

Comment: I faced the same issue with Spark `3.4.1`. Now, I downgraded to `3.3.2`. I hope it will help.